# Widget TextView not updating when using timer

Tags: android, timer, android-widget, widget, textview

Ive got a `TextView` to update the time and date in a widget and have attempted to use a `Timer` to update it every second but it isnt working:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clockIntent, 0);

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.digitalclock);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pendingIntent);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String time = "kk:mm";
                String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
            }
        }, 0, 1000);// Update text every second

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Im going wrong somewhere so if anyone knows, let me know and give me the right way to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update the app widget inside the run()

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String time = "kk:mm";
            String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }, 0, 1000);// Update text every second
```

try it like this this works for me, i think i had the same issue in another app i was using, instead of a timer and timertask use:

```
Handler mHandler;
Runnable continuousRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String time = "kk:mm";
            String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
  mHandler.post(continuousRunnable);
```

Comment: Im guessing the `Handler mHandler;` goes outside the `OnUpdate` method.. Tried it and it doesn't even update once now

Comment: I got it working! I just needed to change `timer.schedule()` to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` i did some research on timers and it turns out `schedule` only runs once whereas `scheduleAtFixedRate` repeats. Thanks for the help @JRowan